# Can I produce several executable files from a single project?

Tags: ada

Lets say you have a client and a server project where these have some packages in common. 
Is it possible to produce two exec files (client, server) from a single Ada project?

Using Ada 2012 with Gnat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  You can see an example of how to do it in the project files in my [LEGO Tools repository](http://repositories.jacob-sparre.dk/lego-tools/src).  The critical part is to list the relevant compilation units in a "Main" clause in the project file like this:

```
for Main use ("build_mpd_file",
              "fractal_landscape",
              "outline_boundaries",
              "pgm_to_ldraw",
              "split_ldraw_file");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
There's nothing special about a subprogram that is to be the main portion of the executable. (There are some restrictions though; IIRC it has to be a paramaterless subprogram, and if a function has to return `Integer`.)

For GNAT, all that's needed is for you to specify which compilation-units are main files.